# Issue creating and using my own exception class

Tags: java, exception

I have a JUnit test class, which I'm new to making. I also trying to learn how to make my own exception classes. I have been creating a BigInt class, and one of the constructors takes in Strings. This bit of code is looping through an array, and its supposed to be checking if the character at each position is an integer. Right now there is an error that says "Unreachable catch block for BigIntFormatException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body" Any ideas for why?

```
    String[] s = { " - - 1424", "+ + 14324", "a142432", "1432 3413",
            "+242134.32421", "", "    \n", "\t ++" };
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        try {
            BigInt b = new BigInt(s[i]);
            assertFalse(true);
        } catch (BigIntFormatException e) {
            assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

So far this is what my BigIntFormatException class just looks like, so any help with this part would be appreciated too.

```
public class BigIntFormatException extends Exception {
    public BigIntFormatException() {
        super();
    }
    public BigIntFormatException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What research have you done? What do you think the error means? The text is pretty obvious.

Comment: Post ur BigInt class code.Add throw clause in the constructor of your Bigint class if u wanna resolve "Unreachable catch block for BigIntFormatException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, this compilation failure is quite clear:  **neither the constructor to `BigInt` nor the assertion *declare* that they are going to throw `BigIntFormatException`**.

Since `Exception` is the class of [checked exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) (meaning that you do have to wrap them in a `try-catch` block), you must declare them to be thrown in your constructor of `BigInt`.

Here's the way you would do that.

```
public BigInt(String str) throws BigIntFormatException {
    // logic
}
```

Comment: Exception is the class of checked exception. how ?

Comment: @AnkitSharma:  Yes.  `Exception` is the superclass of all checked exceptions (meaning that, if you declare it to be thrown, it had better be caught or otherwise thrown).  The other two are `RuntimeException` and `Error`; `RuntimeException` you want to avoid catching since it indicates an underlying problem with your program's state, and `Error` is generally something you **mustn't** catch, as the JVM has met with some untimely disaster.

Comment: Yes. It indicates all Exceptions are not checked exceptions. It might be checked exception or runtime exception. and there is no direct relationship between Exceptions and Errors only they derived from same interface.

Comment: But..`Throwable` is a class...Either way, we digress.

Comment: oops miner mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to throw the exception in your BigInt class

```
    if(/*error condition*/) {
        throw new BigIntFormatException("your message");
    }
```